# GraphX - how do you convert an Array[(VertexId, Array(VertexId)] to Set(VertexId)

Tags: arrays, scala, graph, set

Given that VertexID, I get all directly connected vertexes to that one vertex? (IE, only one edge away) by doing a collectNeighborsId and a lookup using the following code:

```
val ID = 20
val res = graph.collectNeighborIds(EdgeDirection.Out).lookup(ID)
```

the resulting class is an ArrayBuffer(Array(Long) like below:

```
ArrayBuffer(Array(10006, 10009, 10015, 10017, 10025, 10028, 10030, 10037, 10041, 10043, 10046, 10049, 10055, 10056, 10057, 10058, 10059, 10060, 10061, 10068, 10070, 10081, 10082, 10087, 10096, 10101, 10105, 10108, 10111, 10113, 10115, 10119, 10125, 10127, 10129, 10132, 10136, 10137, 10141, 10150, 10152, 10153, 10156, 10158, 10163, 10166, 10167, 10171, 10172, 10173, 10175, 10183, 10186, 10187, 10192, 10193, 10197, 10198, 10201, 10209, 10212, 10213, 10214, 10223, 10226, 10228, 1367, 1654, 1670, 2034, 2146, 2481, 58776, 58778, 58788, 58789))
```

I need to convert it to just a Set[Long].. 
I tried to just convert it by using toSet .. but it still results to Array(Set[Long])

Comment: Which version of GraphX are you using? According to [API docs](collectNeighborIds), `collectNeighborIds` returns a `VertexRDD` which doesn't seem to have a method `lookup`...

Answer (score 0):

Use [`flatten`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/Array.html#flatten[U](implicitasTrav:T=>Traversable[U],implicitm:scala.reflect.ClassTag[U]):Array[U]):

```
scala> val a: Array[Array[Long]] = Array(Array(1, 2), Array(3, 4))
a: Array[Array[Long]] = Array(Array(1, 2), Array(3, 4))

scala> a.flatten.toSet
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Long] = Set(1, 2, 3, 4)
```